# Find equations in word and save each out as separate file

Tags: vba, ms-word, equations

I would like to go through a Word doc, using vba, to take each equation, save it to the clipboard, open a new blank doc, and save that out as a pdf file.

I found two pieces of code which should help me get started but neither get very far:

```
Sub get_eqns()
    Dim eqns As OMath
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For Each eqns In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        With eqns.Range.Select
            '
            '~~> Rest of the code
            '
        End With
    Next

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.OMaths(1) = True Then
            para.Range.OMaths(1).Range.Select
            With Selection
                .CopyAsPicture
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution and wanted to share:

```
Sub get_eqns()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To OMaths.Count
    'your code here

    OMaths.Item(i).Range.Select
    Selection.Copy

       'Do other code here to open new doc, etc

    Selection.Paste
Next i
End Sub
```

I have code for the other parts, the stickler was going through the word doc.

Thanks.