# How to distinguish a MS Equation object from other InlineShapes in a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some MS-Word 2013 documents containing *Microsoft Equation 3.0* equations. Unfortunately, the equations change size from time to time, whether by accident or perhaps due to a bug in Word.

To address this, I wrote a VBA macro to fix the sizes of all the equations in the document back to their original sizes, as follows:

```
Sub FixEquationSize()
    Dim shp As InlineShape
    For Each shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
         shp.ScaleHeight = 100    'The value of ScaleHeight is a percentage
         shp.ScaleWidth = 100
         shp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
         shp.Reset
    Next
End Sub
```

... however this fixes the height and width of all `InlineShape` objects, not just the ones that are equations.

A [previous question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043173/find-equations-in-word-and-save-each-out-as-separate-file) found equations in Word by iterating through `ActiveDocument.OMaths`, but that solution found equations created by `Insert|Symbols|Equation`, not equations inserted by `Insert|Text|Object|Microsoft Equation 3.0` (it is interesting that they are different!).

If I have to iterate through `InlineShapes`, how could I distinguish `InlineShape` objects that are equations from those that are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation 3.0 equations are embedded OLE objects (unlike the newer type of equation which uses a different mechanism. So something like

```
If shp.Type = wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject Then
  If shp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Equation.3" Then
    ' it's an equation object
  End If
End If
```

This assumes that you haven't converted the shapes to something else, e.g. copied/pasted as a graphic of some kind.

Comment: Excellent. That does the job very nicely. Thank you.